# Easiest way to configure local SMTP server to relay through gmail on Windows?

Tags: gmail, smtp

We have gmail for our corporate email provider.

I want to be able to send mail through `smtp.gmail.com` from ASP.NET. I have managed to do this just fine - and it has the benefit of all sent items appearing in the correct sent items folder within gmail. However it can take up to 2-3 seconds to make a connection to `smtp.gmail.com`. Occasionally it will even fail completely. Since this is ASP.NET app I need to be able to reliably send email. I don't want to have to go and create some email daemon of my own - i just want to rely on SMTP.

I've tried with the Virtual SMTP Server on IIS6 but haven't been able to get it to work. An active `current session` is shown for up to a minute and then it disappears.

Do I need to use something like [sendmail](https://serverfault.com/questions/90161/how-to-configure-sendmail-to-send-email-via-gmail-smtp-gmail-com-using-port-46) to [do this](http://www.phinesolutions.com/sendmail-gmail-smtp-relay-howto.html) - or some other free SMTP relay that gives me better control? I even found a sourceforge project called '[Gmail SMTP Relay](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsr/)' - and the hosted server we're using has    installed - which has its own SMTP server.

I'd prefer something graphical - and most of all I'd prefer the Microsoft SMTP server becasue I already have it installed.

Comment: Exactly same solution like @simon's link but with better explanation and guidance. http://www.vsysad.com/2014/01/configure-iis-smtp-server-to-use-gmail-to-forward-messages/ I had the need of local smtp server for configuring MS SSRS reports automatic email delivery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this explanation here of exactly what I needed (when using IIS) :

http://fmuntean.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-server-to-forward-emails-using-a-gmail-account/

I am sending mail using this C# code

```
var client  = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 587);
client.EnableSsl = false;
```

Note: the communication between my C# app and my local SMTP server is not encrypted (hence the EnableSsl=false) - but the communication between my SMTP server and GMAIL *is* encrypted (see the linked doc for more).

**Important tip:** If you are using the Microsoft SMTP client to relay mail make sure you don't have any domains in the 'Default SMTP Virtual Server > Domains' list. if so any email addressed to those domains will end up in `C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Drop` - which is probably not what you want in this instance. I just renamed `mydomain.com` to (literally) `example.com` after having problems with outgoing mail not actually going out.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I see what you meant now. You wanted to use your own SMTP server as your local point, and Gmail's servers as the actual email sender.

Comment: right - basically its about speed. it takes a few ms to send to my local server vs. up to 2-3 seconds to send to gmail - which may even fail

Answer (score 5):

I fought with this for a few weeks. Here are the settings that I'm using on 3 ASP.NET websites that use SMTP gateway to send their emails:

Address: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587

1) The port is very important. You may have to enter it like smtp.gmail.com:587 in your SMTP server. I haven't touched Microsoft SMTP in years, so I can't remember what the setup screen looks like.

2) Make sure to enable **SSL** for SMTP, as gmail requires it.

3) SMTP Authentication should be set to **Basic**.

4) Make sure that you are using an actual email and not an email alias to authenticate. This one gave me lot of trouble.

This is how I got it working.

Comment: which SMTP gateway are you using? thats the main thing I don't understand how to configure

Comment: i already have these settings in my web.config. i need to know how to use an intermediary SMTP server to relay them