# Linode w/ Google Apps - how to get mail from PHP working?

Tags: sendmail, wordpress, g-suite, linode

I have a CentOS Linode instance that I'm running as a LAMP stack. I'm also using Google Apps for email. I have my MX records pointing at google's servers and everything is working in terms of relaying my emails just fine.

However, sendmail on the box is not working correctly, which means that emails from PHP (wordpress) are not being delivered.

Looking at the local mail I can see these messages repeated in the logs -

```
   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
<my email addr>... Deferred: Connection refused by aspmx.l.google.com.
```

I have no experience configuring sendmail - can anyone tell me where to start in working out this issue? I've done a lot of googling but to no avail.

Comment: Perhaps the title should be edited to WordPress w/ Google Apps... to offer more relevancy, as this isn't only tied to Linode.

Comment: @Alex see http://serverfault.com/questions/90161/how-to-configure-sendmail-to-send-email-via-gmail-smtp-gmail-com-using-port-4 for configuring Sendmail to relay via GMail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably want to use this WordPress addon: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/.

It allows WP to send e-mail through smtp rather than the PHP `mail()` function.

SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com

SMTP Port: either 465 with SSL encryption or 587 with TLS Encryption

SSL Authentication:    Yes

Username: richard.nichols@fulldomain.com

Password: `;)`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick - I've since found that mail relay is only available if you are using the paid version of Google Apps, so I was never going to get it to word the way I expected anyhow :)